# How to store only URL of uploaded file using paperclip in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip, aws-sdk

I need a help on storing the URL of Uploaded image using paperclip on AWS S3.
I don't want auto generate fields in my database, instead of them i just need URL of that field.
I don't want to use any style for re-size the image.

Suppose my field for image is "image", then paperclip add 4 fields to my table as follow

- image_file_name
- image_content_type
- image_file_size
- image_updated_at

But, instead of them, I just need "image_url" in my database. and whenever i delete record that uploaded image is also delete from AWS S3.

is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if you can remove those field and expect Paperclip to work properly, but you can add a new field and possibly fill it in in a before_save hook with something like `self.image_url = image.url(:medium)`. Also note that if you delete the record, Paperclip is smart enough to delete the S3 object, too (in case you didn't know).